# Access array from the static translation file

Tags: plugin-development, templating, localization

This is the scenario: I need the translations strings in both Twig and JS (For React). Of course I'm covered in the [Twig part.](https://craftcms.com/support/static-translations), and I don't want to maintain two different files (php and json). So I've created a custom module, where I can read the files, like:

```
public function getTranslations($language, $translationsFileName = 'site')
{
    if (file_exists(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/translations/' . $language . '/' . $translationsFileName . '.php')) {
        return require_once(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/translations/' . $language . '/' . $translationsFileName . '.php');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
{{ craft.translations.getTranslations(craft.locale) | json_encode | raw }}
```

It works, but, is this a good way? Is there a default Craft/Yii way?

Comment: Would it be an option for you to do it like Craft does it in the CP (I use the same way in my frontend) instead of just serializing the entire array?

Comment: Like {{ "var" | translate }} you mean? Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: No I mean by using the `RegisterTranslation` https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-view.html#method-registertranslations function in your frontend. You only need to define a Craft object and copy the `Craft.t` function

Comment: @RobinSchambach do you have an example of how to use registerTranslations?  I don't understand what the $category and $messages arguments are.  I tried passing in site handles and strings to translate but no go.

Comment: @biko This comes from Yii2 https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n You have different translation categories, for example `site` for everything site related or `app` )that's yii2 internal category. The message argument is the thing you want to translate.
For example `registerTranslations('site', ['foo', 'bar'))` would include translations for the word `foo` and `bar` in the category `site` (default one)

Comment: @RobinSchambach thank you!  I think that this might not work well because I want the whole object map available.  I've worked around it and made the php object map available in element-api.php.  Would be nice if there was an official way to do this.

Comment: I usually grab all translations and return them all in my JS driven projects too. Just not via elements-API but via YII2 REST API.